# The changes I want to make to origin show up as merge conflicts

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I pulled the remote branch "develop", made a new branch "branch", and made my changes.

```
git add .

git commit -m "Made necessary changes"

git push
```

Now I want to make a PR from myfork/branch to origin/develop but it shows that there are merge conflicts. The conflicts, however, are exactly the changes I had to make. There are no other merge conflicts. My boss is telling me there is something missing in my pull/push steps. Any ideas?

Comment: Hard to say with what little you've shown us. Was the source branch up to date?  If not, the solution is to merge the source branch into your development branch before creating the PR.

Comment: What does `git status` show?

Comment: My branch is up to date with origin/develop and no changes show up in git status. Everything I did was committed and then pushed

Comment: How did you make your branch?

Comment: git checkout develop -- 
git pull origin develop -- 
git branch branch -- 
git checkout branch --

Comment: I assume you mean `git checkout develop; git pull origin develop; git branch branch; git checkout branch`. Those dashes mean things in Git. :) That all looks fine. Still hard to say. Maybe try again.

Comment: Yes sorry I meant to put a break line in there. Yes I'll try that thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check the history you have on your local repository :

```
# update remote branches :
git fetch

# inspect the history of the following branches :
git log --graph --oneline myfork/branch develop origin/develop
```

You should see that `myfork/branch` and `origin/develop` have diverged : `origin/develop` has received commits that aren't part of your branch
(if this isn't the case, please add a comment)

---

To fix this : you can either

- rebase your local branch on top of `origin/develop`
  you will have to fix the conflicts on your machine
- or discard your branch, start from `origin/develop` and re-code the fix :

```
# from myfork/branch :
git checkout myfork/branch

# discard all local changes, and move to origin/develop :
git reset --hard origin/develop

# fix code ...

# add & commit
git add file1 file2 ...
git commmit
```

A word of caution with `git reset --hard` : of you have some changes on your disk which aren't tracked or committed, executing `git reset --hard` will silently erase them. If you want to put them aside, it is a good habit to at least `git stash` them away.